# Last Windows Updates Stopped Ability to Print to My Wireless Printer

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, network-printer

Since installing the last 3 Windows updates: KB5028166, KB5028853 and Servicing Stack 10.0.19041.3205, my computer can no longer access the wireless printer used by the household. I am running Windows 10, v22H2. Message was "Printer Offline" even though it was on and connected to my network. I followed all advice for fixing. The last was to reinstall printer drivers. Now it can't complete installation. Although the printer as Fax is listed, the regular printer is no longer listed. Printer is HP Officejet 3830. Other computers in the household can still print to it. Any ideas? Should I try uninstalling the Windows Updates?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Windows 10 or Windows 10 printing.  Try deleting anything in the Print Queue, restart and try installing the driver again. Also try disconnecting and reconnecting the wireless printer in case it got lost

Comment: I found the problem. `Printer is HP ...` - seriously, HP printer drivers should be shot for treason against humanity

Comment: @Cathy Gansen - Have you got your printer working yet?  I use predominantly HP printers and no Windows Update issues with them.

Comment: Still not working. I have deleted print queue, restarted the printer (which shows connected to network), restarted computer, reinstalled drivers to no avail. Others in my household can still print, but my computer does no longer recognizes the printer. Do you think I should uninstall the Windows updates?